# Print statement does not show value (Oracle SQL Developer)

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, procedure

I want to display value with print statement.

```
var p_result number;

exec package.procedure(:p_result);

print p_result;
```

But it does not show number on Script Output like below.

```
P_RESULT
------
```

Does anybody have any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please show us your code. That SHOULD work. Here is a working example.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE so_print (x OUT VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
 x := 'hello, SO';
END;
/

var p_result varchar2(20);

exec so_print(:p_result);

print p_result;
```

And the output

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


P_RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
hello, SO
```

Comment: just tested with an integer, and that's prints as well (42)